# JS Date issues with adding 1 week

Tags: javascript, date

I am having an issue and was wondering if someone could give me a little insight as to why. The following code is working to add one week to a date:

```
while (c.getStamp() < b.getStamp()) {
    var f = this.getWeek(c);
    e.push(f);
    c = (c.getStamp() + 604800).toDate();
}

...

Date.prototype.getStamp = function() {
    return Math.round(this.getTime() / 1e3);
};

Number.prototype.toDate = function() {
    return new Date(this * 1e3);
};
```

I'm trying to get the following to work but it creates a continuous loop:

```
while (c.getStamp() < b.getStamp()) {
    var f = this.getWeek(c);
    e.push(f);
    c = new Date(c.getFullYear(), c.getMonth(), c.getDate + 7, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Where `c = JS Date, ie 05/01/12` and `b = JS Date, ie 05/31/12`

Comment: Wow, I've never actually seen someone use `1e3` when not playing code golf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed the `()` after `c.getDate`.

Aside from that, you can just do this:

```
c.setTime(c.getTime()+7*24*60*60*1000); // adds 1 week to the date
```

Answer (score 3):

To add a week to a date, the simplest method is to add 7 days:

```
var now = new Date();

// add one week exactly
now.setDate(now.getDate() + 7);
```

If you add the equivalent of 7*24hrs in milliseconds, you will be incorrect if the week crosses a daylight saving boundary. And the above is a bit clearer in the code.

In your code:

```
> while (c.getStamp() < b.getStamp()) {
```

if `c` and `d` are both date objects, then:

```
while (c < b) {
```

is more efficient, less error prone and less to write.

```
>      var f = this.getWeek(c);
```

What is `f`? What does `f.getWeek` return?

```
>      e.push(f);
>      c = (c.getStamp() + 604800).toDate();
```

Presumably you want to add one week to c, so:

```
  c.setDate(c.getDate() + 7);
```

Later...

```
>    c = new Date(c.getFullYear(), c.getMonth(), c.getDate + 7, 0, 0, 0);
> --------------------------------------------------------^
```

You have a syntax error and have not zeroed the milliseconds. This seems like an even longer-winded way to a a week to `c`, see above.

> Where c = JS Date, ie 05/01/12 and b = JS Date, ie 05/31/12

Please note that this in an international forum, regional specific expressions should be avoided or explained if used. Are the above in the US–specific mm/dd/yyyy format? A more widely recognised format is dd/mm/yyyy or better to use an ISO8601 format: yyy-mm-dd (which should be supported natively by all browsers compliant with ES5, but they all aren't yet).

Oh, and the `getStamp` and `toDate` methods seem like attempts at rounding to the nearest second. You might try a function that does just that in one go:

```
Date.prototype.roundToSecond = function() {
  this.setMilliseconds(this.getMilliseconds() > 499? 1000 : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kolink has the right answer, but you might also want to take a look at the [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) date library if your doing alot of work with manipulating dates and formatting them.

Comment: This might be better off as a comment.

Comment: It would be a fine answer if it showed a code example, which would illustrate why this is such a great lib to look into